# CSS и откидное меню

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при наводке на sub-menu сделать такую же анимацию что и при наводке на сам значок меню?
пытаюсь сделать при помощи ~ но не получилось, помогите пожалуйста, не получается.

html

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <main>
      <section class="menu">
         <section class="sub-menu">
            <section class="sub-sub-menu1"></section>
            <section class="sub-sub-menu2"></section>
            <section class="sub-sub-menu3"></section>
         </section>
      </section>
      <section class="section-menu">
         <section class="sub-section-menu">
            <a href="#">Домашняя</a>
            <a href="#">Жанры</a>
            <a href="#">Аниме</a>
            <a href="#">Онгоинг</a>
            <a href="#">Топ - 100</a>
         </section>
      </section>
   </main>
```

css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orelega+One&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');

*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
li{list-style-type: none;}
a{text-decoration: none;}
body{background: #111111;max-width: 2000px;}
main{max-width: 100%;height: 60px;background: #111111;position: sticky;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 11;}

.logo{float: left;font-size: 48px;margin: 4px 5px;font-weight: 500;color: #5a2e98;font-family: 'Orelega One', cursive;}
.searchForm{float: left;margin: 12px;height: 25px;}
.search{width: 235px;outline: none;height: 100%;background: #1c1c1c;;border: none;padding: 7px;color: white;font-size: 20px;border-radius: 4px;}
.random{float: left;margin: 20px 10px;}
.random>a{color: #febb00;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 500;font-family: 'Orelega One', cursive;}
.avatar{width: 40px;height: 40px;;float: right;margin: 10px;background: #F0D8D8;}
.menu{width: 40px;height: 40px;border-radius: 50%;float: right;margin: 10px;position: relative;overflow: hidden;}

.sub-sub-menu1{width: 50px;height: 7px;background: #5a2e98;position: absolute;top: 0px;transition: .5s;border-radius: 10px;left: -5px;}
.sub-sub-menu2{width: 50px;height: 8px;background: #5a2e98;position: absolute;top: 16px;transition: .5s;border-radius: 10px;left: -5px;}
.sub-sub-menu3{width: 50px;height: 7px;background: #5a2e98;position: absolute;top: 33px;transition: .5s;border-radius: 10px;left: -5px;}

.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu1{transform: rotate(45deg);left: -22px;top: 20px;position: absolute;background: white;}
.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu2{transform: rotate(90deg);left: -5px;bottom: 0px;background: white;}
.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu3{transform: rotate(135deg);left: 12px;top: 20px;background: white;}


.section-menu{width: 220px;height: 330px;position: absolute;right: 0;z-index: 15;background: #ffffff00;top: 40px;right: 10px;display: none;}
.sub-section-menu{width: 210px;height: 300px;background: rgb(224, 134, 134);position: absolute;top: 20px;right: 0;border-radius: 10px;background: #5a2e98;}
.sub-section-menu{display: flex;flex-direction: column;}
.sub-section-menu>a{text-align: center;margin: 16px;color: white;font-size: 18px;font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;}
.sub-section-menu>a:hover{background: #7555a1d0;}
.menu:hover ~.section-menu{display: block;}

.section-menu:hover{display: block;}


footer{max-width: 100%;height: 247px;background: #111111;bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: убрал, но как добавить сделать анимацию постоянной? при наводке на меню и подменю?

Comment: при наведении на меню, появляется стрелка(.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu1), но при наводке на выбор подменю, она пропадает, при попытке сделать section-menu:hover ~.sub-sub-menu1{transform: rotate(45deg);} - она не работает. как это исправить? что бы анимация стрелки не пропадала после наводки на подменю

Comment: Да! спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orelega+One&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background: #111111;
  max-width: 2000px;
}

main {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #111111;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 4px 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #5a2e98;
  font-family: 'Orelega One', cursive;
}

.searchForm {
  float: left;
  margin: 12px;
  height: 25px;
}

.search {
  width: 235px;
  outline: none;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  ;
  border: none;
  padding: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.random {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

.random>a {
  color: #febb00;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Orelega One', cursive;
}

.avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  ;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #F0D8D8;
}

.menu {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub-sub-menu1, main:hover .sub-sub-menu1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #5a2e98;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: -5px;
}

.sub-sub-menu2, main:hover .sub-sub-menu2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #5a2e98;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: -5px;
}

.sub-sub-menu3, main:hover .sub-sub-menu3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #5a2e98;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: -5px;
}

.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu1, .hover:hover .sub-sub-menu1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: -22px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}

.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu2, .hover:hover .sub-sub-menu2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -5px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: white;
}

.menu:hover .sub-sub-menu3, .hover:hover .sub-sub-menu3 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: 12px;
  top: 20px;
  background: white;
}

.section-menu {
  width: 220px;
  height: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  background: #ffffff00;
  top: 40px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.sub-section-menu {
  width: 210px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(224, 134, 134);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #5a2e98;
}

.sub-section-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sub-section-menu>a {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.sub-section-menu>a:hover {
  background: #7555a1d0;
}

.menu:hover~.section-menu {
  display: block;
}

.section-menu:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
<section class="hover">
    <section class="menu">
    <section class="sub-sub-menu1"></section>
    <section class="sub-sub-menu2"></section>
    <section class="sub-sub-menu3"></section>
  </section>
  <section class="section-menu">
    <section class="sub-section-menu">
      <a href="#">Домашняя</a>
      <a href="#">Жанры</a>
      <a href="#">Аниме</a>
      <a href="#">Онгоинг</a>
      <a href="#">Топ - 100</a>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
</main>
```